# Enforce time constraint on how long an App can be used

Tags: linux, algorithm, security, unix

User downloads an App (which assume is a game) from server. I need to enforce time constraint on how long a user can run an Application on a system.

eg. Starting from the time of installation, user can use the Application till only 5 days.

My problem is, if I depend on system time/day etc for implementing this logic, user might change the system time and overcome the logic.

Platform: Linux/C++

P.S.: I have to assume a case in which user decides to not connect to internet at all after he downloaded the Application. Since I don't have network access so can't rely on server based storage about Application's installation date/time etc.

Can someone give a clue how this kind of behavior is implemented in Applications which give a trial period of their usage?

---

Edit:

I am adding the Algo which I am thinking:

At installation time :

1. At the time of installation store the current system date.
2. Store this info in an encrypted form into a file DRM.txt

On App startup :

1. Open the file and decrypt the installation date.
2. Get the current date from system.
3. Match if the application is allowed to be executed according to the number of days that have passed since user installed it.
4. If allowed, start the App else give error msg and return.

Problem:

1. Let at the time of installation system date is 19/12/2012 and user is allowed to use the App only for 4 days that is till 22/12//2012. Thus, 19/12/2012 is stored into DRM.txt.
2. After 4 days user changes the system date back to 20/12/2012, then my logic to check will allow this Application to run.

Hope this clarifies what I am trying to say.

Comment: Do you want your expiry to occur after a number of calendar days?  Or after a number of seconds of runtime?  Or some other criteria?  Pick your rules, come up with some sample code to implement them, and if it doesn't work, include it in your question.  StackOverflow is about *your code*.

Comment: @ghoti It should expire after a number of calender days. And since I can for-see the problem in implementation beforehand, isn't it better that I should focus on the Algorithm first rather than implementation ? (And that is why the Algo tag and not C++!)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved through encryption, for example storing a date into an encrypted file, note that this won't prevent reverse engineering, etc, etc, etc

Comment: Note that you'll *never* have full control over what happens to your program or what's going on in the users machine, meaning that the goal here is *the harder the better*. Also, if you are feeling a little neurotic, you can always combine various methods (timer, countdown, encryption, online check...)

Comment: Jacobs, what made me wonder was that I install so many programs with trial versions on Windows ( say 15 days, with no internet requirements ), but their policy works perfectly fine even if I mess with the system date. That is why I wanted to understand the logic they might be following.

Answer (score 0):

Save and check the time when start and stop the APP. 
If the current time is much shorter than the saved time, then you can think it is cheating.